# PWM to analog RC based filter with minimum analog voltage level

Tags: electrical-engineering, pwm

Trying to design a circuit to accomplish the following:

1. 5V PWM signal is converted to 0-2.5V analog voltage
2. The analog voltage should never drop below a certain minimum voltage level, when PWM is 0 or filtered PWM signal results in a voltage level less than this minimum.

I know I can do this with a microcontroller and other IC's but looking for a simple solution. I've come up with the following. A voltage regulator produces 2.5V. An n-channel FET switched by the PWM signal produces a 2.5V PWM signal. This 2.5V PWM signal is converted via RC filter to 0 - 2.5V analog voltage.
I also have a voltage divider to feed the minimum voltage level to the capacitor through a diode. I am aware I will need to compensate for the voltage drop over the diode.

I want to keep the 2.5V voltage regulator to guarantee a 2.5V voltage level, since the 5V PWM signal may be 3.3V PWM.

[image]